# Keras - monitoring quantities with TensorBoard during training

Tags: monitoring, keras, tensorboard, autoencoder

With Tensorflow it is possible to monitor quantities during training, using tf.summary.

Is it possible to do the same using Keras ? Could you include an example by modifying the code at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py and monitoring the KL loss (defined [at line 53](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py#L53))

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a workaround consists in adding the quantities to monitor as metrics when compiling the model.

For instance, I wanted to monitor the KL divergence (in the context of variational auto encoders), so I wrote this:

```
def kl_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + K.log(z_var_0+1e-8) - K.square(z_mean_0) - z_var_0, axis=-1)
    return kl_loss

vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=vae_loss, metrics=['accuracy', kl_loss])
```

And it does what I need

Comment: It is worth noticing that if `loss=None`, no metrics will be evaluated. This is commonly the case for the Keras VAE examples.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the TensorBoard callback? [1]

```
tensorboard = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs',
                 histogram_freq=1, 
                 write_graph=True, 
                 write_images=False)
vae.fit(x_train,
        shuffle=True,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
        callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

Then run:

```
tensorboard --logdir=./logs
```

You could write a modified version of the callback to handle the specific items you are interested in.

[1] https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard

Comment: Tensorboard is very nice but it isn't flexible enough. For instance, if my loss has too parts a and b, a+b being the total loss (but is computed on the same output of the model), I cannot monitor a and b separately, but only their sum a+b. I would like to be able to monitor both, and tf.summary just allows to do that, but I'm not sure how to that with Keras

Comment: The Tensorboard callback uses `tf.summary.histogram` and `tf.summary.FileWriter` to dump out the logs for Tensorboard. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L631 so it's probably easy enough to define your own lambda callback that sends the options you want to tf.summary

Comment: I hadn't thought about looking the callback.TensorBoard source code, there is plenty of useful code here. Thank you very much, it really helps !