# Writing summary.scalar with Dataset API and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I use tensorflow Keras API and try to add custom scalar to the tensorboard but nothing except the loss is displayed.

Here is the code for the model:

```
embedding_in = Embedding(
    input_dim=vocab_size + 1 + 1,  
    output_dim=dim,
    mask_zero=True,
)

embedding_out = Embedding(
    input_dim=vocab_size + 1 + 1,  
    output_dim=dim,
    mask_zero=True,
)

input_a = Input((None,))
input_b = Input((None,))
input_c = Input((None, None))

emb_target = embedding_in(input_a)
emb_context = embedding_out(input_b)
emb_negatives = embedding_out(input_c)

emb_gru = GRU(dim, return_sequences=True)(emb_target)

num_negatives = tf.shape(input_c)[-1]


def make_logits(tensors):
    emb_gru, emb_context, emb_negatives = tensors
    true_logits = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(emb_gru, emb_context), axis=2)
    true_logits = tf.expand_dims(true_logits, -1)
    sampled_logits = tf.squeeze(
        tf.matmul(emb_negatives, tf.expand_dims(emb_gru, axis=2),
                  transpose_b=True), axis=3)
    true_logits = true_logits*0
    sampled_logits = sampled_logits*0

    logits = K.concatenate([true_logits, sampled_logits], axis=-1)
    return logits


logits = Lambda(make_logits)([emb_gru, emb_context, emb_negatives])

mean = tf.reduce_mean(logits)
tf.summary.scalar('mean_logits', mean)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b, input_c], outputs=[logits])
```

In particular, I want to see the evolution of `mean_logits` scalar after each batch.

I create and compile the model like this:

```
model = build_model(dim, vocab_size)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
]
```

I use tf Dataset API to the model:

```
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
        model.fit(iterator, steps_per_epoch=100, 
                  callbacks=callbacks,
                  validation_data=iterator,
                  validation_steps=1
                 )
```

However, I don't get any mean_logits graph in the tensorboard and it's not in the graphs. 
[image]

How can I track `mean_logits` scalar in tensorboard after each batch?

I use tf 1.12 and keras 2.1.

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue. It seems that Keras `TensorBoard` callback not gonna write all existing summaries automatically, but only those [registered as metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501022/keras-monitoring-quantities-with-tensorboard-during-training) (and appear in `logs` dict). Updating the `logs` object is a nice trick as it allows to use the values in other callbacks, see [Early stopping and learning rate schedule based on custom metric in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410953/early-stopping-and-learning-rate-schedule-based-on-custom-metric-in-keras). I can see several possibilities:

**1. Using Lambda callback**

Something like this:

```
eval_callback = LambdaCallback(
    on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: logs.update(
        {'mean_logits': K.eval(mean)}
    ))
```

**2. Custom TensorBoard callback**

You can also subclass the callback and define your own logic. For instance, my workaround for learning rate monitoring:

```
class Tensorboard(Callback):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    def __init__(self,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                 log_dir='./log',                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                 write_graph=True):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        self.write_graph = write_graph                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        self.log_dir = log_dir                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    def set_model(self, model):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        self.model = model                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        self.sess = K.get_session()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        if self.write_graph:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.log_dir, self.sess.graph)                                                                                                                                                                                        
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.log_dir)                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        logs.update({'learning_rate': float(K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr))})                                                                                                                                                                                   
        self._write_logs(logs, epoch)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    def _write_logs(self, logs, index):                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        for name, value in logs.items():                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            if name in ['batch', 'size']:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                continue                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            summary = tf.Summary()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            summary_value = summary.value.add()                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            if isinstance(value, np.ndarray):                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                summary_value.simple_value = value.item()                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                summary_value.simple_value = value                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            summary_value.tag = name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            self.writer.add_summary(summary, index)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

        self.writer.flush()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    def on_train_end(self, _):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        self.writer.close()
```

Here, I just add 'learning_rate' to `logs` explicitly. But this way can be much more flexible and powerful.

**3. Metrics trick**

[Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/keras-users/rEJ1xYqD3AM/1C3extflDgAJ) is another interesting workaround. What you need to do is to pass a custom metric function to model's `compile()` call  which returns aggregated summary tensor. The idea is to make Keras pass your aggregated summary operation to every session.run call and return it's result as metric:

```
x_entropy_t = K.sum(p_t * K.log(K.epsilon() + p_t), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
full_policy_loss_t = -res_t + X_ENTROPY_BETA * x_entropy_t
tf.summary.scalar("loss_entropy", K.sum(x_entropy_t))
tf.summary.scalar("loss_policy", K.sum(-res_t))
tf.summary.scalar("loss_full", K.sum(full_policy_loss_t))

summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("logs/" + args.name)

def summary(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.summary.merge_all()

value_policy_model.compile(optimizer=Adagrad(), loss=loss_dict, metrics=[summary])
l = value_policy_model.train_on_batch(x_batch, y_batch)
l_dict = dict(zip(value_policy_model.metrics_names, l))

summary_writer.add_summary(l_dict['value_summary'], global_step=iter_idx)
summary_writer.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you for many solutions, but surprisingly none of them works. In particular, the first one requires inputs data to feed inside `mean`. As I use Dataset API and there are no explicit batches, I can't do `K.eval`.

Comment: The second one I think has similar issues besides the fact that it's not clear how retrieve `mean` variable.

Comment: The third one I saw before and tried but the catch is that it requires `iter_idx`, which basically implies that instead of doing `.fit` method, it uses `.train_on_batch` method and provides the batches independently in the for loop. And I don't want to change `fit` method with `train_on_batch` because it has fewer arguments. So I guess there is no support for custom TB if you use Dataset API.

Comment: `iter_idx` is just an integer value for the batch number. I would try to find some workaround. For instance, put `summary_writer.add_summary` inside a custom callback at `on_batch_end`. Then you got the value as `batch` argument. I cannot run your code, so it is difficult to provide a working solution like that.